# Apple Wireless Keyboard not connecting automatically on wake

Tags: macos, bluetooth, keyboard

Recently I'm using my MacBook Air mostly in clamshell mode, with an  Wireless Keyboard and an  Magic Trackpad paired. Sometimes, weeks pass by without even opening the lid: connecting it at the office, putting to sleep, connecting it at home etc.

From time to time, the bluetooth keyboard does not connect back on wake automatically, as the bluetooth trackpad does: I have to open the lid, type in my password, then pair the keyboard to use it.

What is the problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you have any other devices in the house that this keyboard could be connecting to?

Comment: I might suspect my flat-mate's MacBook, but the keyboard has been paired since day one to my laptop. Shouldn't that prevent it from being "hijacked"?

Comment: it can still cause the problems. If your laptop is off and it connects to his first then it will never connect to yours. It does not matter if it was paired to yours first, if its also paired with another machine it will connect to which ever one is turned on first.

Answer (score 1):

**Resetting the SMC** should be able to fix the issue. Note that this will reboot the MacBook, so you will lose any unsaved work.

- Shut down the computer.
- Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to
  the Mac if its not already connected.
- On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option
  keys and the power button at the same time.
- Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
- Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Note: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.